# CodeIgniter cart class Arabic regex

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode

The Cart.php under system/library has a regex pattern definition that is not enabling me to use Arabic for name values. This works:

```
$data = array(
  'id' => "221212",
  'qty' => 1,
  'price' => 21.2,
  'name' => 'dasdasdas'
);
```

But this fails because of Arabic in the name:

```
$data = array(
  'id' => "221212",
  'qty' => 1,
  'price' => 21.2,
  'name' => 'عمر'
);
```

Now in the Cart.php class, I found the following:

```
// These are the regular expression rules that we use to validate the product ID and product name
  var $product_id_rules = '\.a-z0-9_-';
  // alpha-numeric, dashes, underscores, or periods
  var $product_name_rules = '\.\:\-_a-z0-9';
  // alphanumeric, dashes, underscores, colons or periods
```

I am concerned with the name rules. Clearly this is the problem because later on there is a check:

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[".$this->product_name_rules."]+$/i", $items['name'])) {
  log_message('error', 'An invalid name was submitted as the product name: '.$items['name'].' The name can only contain alpha-numeric characters, dashes, underscores, colons, and spaces');
  return FALSE;
}
```

How can I replace the name rules string to work with Arabic? I have a very poor background with regex, so please help out.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What of these is modifiable? You probably should be able to match arabic with this regex - `\.a-z0-9_-\p{Arabic}`. The catch is it won't work without adding `/u` modifier to the regex as well.

Comment: Not very clear on what you just said but I tried multiple patterns not working neither one of them. Probably my use of them is incorrect. that's why I request code illustration

Comment: If its possible, you can add the arabic name as product option and use name as alphanumeric e-g
            'id' => "221212",
            'qty' => 1, 
            'price' => 21.2,
            'name' => 'umar',
            'options' => array('arabic_name' => 'عمر')

Comment: I thought about that @AbdulHaseeb but I am sure there must be a way to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

It will work, if you change your `$product_name_rules` (partial) pattern into this:

```
var $product_name_rules = '\.\:\-_a-z0-9\p{Arabic}';
```

... then add `/u` modifier to the pattern actually used by `preg_match`:

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[".$this->product_name_rules."]+$/iu", 
            $items['name'])) { ... }
```

Quoting the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> **u (PCRE_UTF8)**
>
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE 
>   that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. 
>   This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix 
>   and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.

Comment: This still didn't work. Because when I do the above changes (copy & paste), the add to cart button doesn't work. When I change the arabic name to english, it works and contents displayed.

Comment: Could you add version of PHP and encoding used to the question? This snippet actually works locally quite well, when I just copy-paste the string from your question - so either `/u` modifier is not supported, or encoding is not UTF-8, I suppose...

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.10 and am not sure what u mean by encoding?

Comment: Please check [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: btw you not adding /u only u have /iu in the above example. I dont know what they both mean but thought should bring it up

Comment: I've added the description of `/u` to the answer; as for `/i`, it just makes the pattern case-insensitive (so `a-z` range will match `A-Z` too).

Comment: so should I give up on this? codeigniter literally sucks all the way because of this.

Comment: Could you just show what's in your site `<meta charset` header? (or equivalent `meta http-equiv='content-type'`... one).

Comment: since this is all happening in controller, then there is no meta defined. but in the html page (i.e. products.php), I have <meta charset="UTF-8">

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept other characters, you have to modify $this->cart->product_name_rules after you have loaded the cart library.

```
$this->load->library('cart');
$this->cart->product_name_rules = '\.a-z0-9_-\p{Arabic}';
```

Comment: How about the setting the rules to empty string to check if it works? 

$this->cart->product_name_rules = '';

Answer (score 0):

Change `product_name` regex to the following, which allows all:

```
var $product_name_rules = '^.'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that partially works. There is a problem: when I set database in codeiginter config to utf8 it works (but display of information is ?????. when I change database charset to utf-8, the words are showing but insert failing. Why?

Comment: try changing your table and table fields, all to UTF-8 collation, see the following pic:
http://i995.photobucket.com/albums/af77/lethanhpsp/new.png

Comment: I did that and even database and all tables to utf8_unicode_ci. Still not working. I can't believe how unreliable this codeigniter is :(

Comment: yes sir I did...left nothing in the database unturned...i attached the snapshot