# CodeIgniter charset to UTF-8

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode

I had a problem with inserting Arabic product names to Cart in CodeIgniter. That was fixed by overriding the `Cart.class` library `$product_name_rules` with `$this->cart->product_name_rules = "^."`

Now that works fine but there is another problem. It only works when I set `$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';` in the database config file. Naturally this returns all strings from database as ????. If I change that utf8 to utf-8, it starts displaying the retrieved information correctly, but the cart refuses to work.

What to do?[image]

[image]

it is either the cart works(utf-8 in database config) or the arabic works (utf8 in database)

Comment: i have answered you here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514736/codeigniter-cart-class-arabic-regex/13522066#comment18516664_13522066

Comment: yup looked at it...but because it is a new question with encoding more than codeigniter cart class, I had to open new question. I believe this is one of the rules here or something.

Comment: maybe you should google something, i found this http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/194698/

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the Collation of your table column which is storing your Arabic  product name, you can change its collation to utf8_general_ci or appropriate for Arabic chars

Comment: Yes I have...I think this is a bug in codeigniter when it comes to Arabic. Maybe there is no solution? Been trying until now and no luck

Comment: utf-8 is sufficient for doing this, I don't think codeigniter has a bug, what Collation are you using for your column,

Comment: when are you getting this error, while showing in browser or while checking in database

Comment: but arabic is showing for some products, also have you added proper doctype for your webpage

Answer (score 0):

There is a table used by CI for sessions. Although the table collation is set to UTF8 but the columns themselves are not. So when selection is made from shopping cart, data is stored as ??? because not unicode. Changed that collation to unicode and working perfectly.